# Cmake add_library with flag

Tags: cmake

Is it possible to put a flag inside a cmake add_library function so that I reduce duplicate code.  e.g.

```
add_library(somename SHARED

    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:xxx_objs>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:yyy_objs>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:zzz_objs>
    #if(INCLUDE_SOME_FLAG)
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:aaa_objs>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:bbb_objs>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ccc_objs>
    #endif(INCLUDE_SOME_FLAG)
)
```

If I try I get the error:  "Cannot find source file:"
If I remove the flag it works OK.  I guess it thinks the flag is a source file, any way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set(somename_objs
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:xxx_objs>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:yyy_objs>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:zzz_objs>)
if (INCLUDE_SOME_FLAG)
    list(APPEND somename_objs
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:aaa_objs>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:bbb_objs>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ccc_objs>)
endif ()
add_library(somename SHARED ${somename_objs})
```